# python 3.10 pip install libraries

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am using the latest (still demo, but yet the last version before the release) python - which is 3.10.0rc2.

I have issues with installing standard libraries such as numpy. I am using `pip install`, `python -m pip` etc.

cmd output:

```
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.21.2.zip (10.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\python.exe' 'c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\mateu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpg9tjgygv'
       cwd: C:\Users\mateu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c3kg6xo0\numpy_a0f8cbcefbea46f59d0a8ef8b828b848
  Complete output (208 lines):
  setup.py:63: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.21.2 may not yet support Python 3.10.
    warnings.warn(
  Running from numpy source directory.
  C:\Users\mateu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c3kg6xo0\numpy_a0f8cbcefbea46f59d0a8ef8b828b848\tools\cythonize.py:69: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion
  Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
  Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
  Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
  Cythonizing sources
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  blis_info:
    libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\libs']
  get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
  customize GnuFCompiler
  Could not locate executable g77
  Could not locate executable f77
  customize IntelVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable ifort
  Could not locate executable ifl
  customize AbsoftFCompiler
  Could not locate executable f90
  customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable DF
  customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable efl
  customize Gnu95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable gfortran
  Could not locate executable f95
  customize G95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable g95
  customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
  customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
  Could not locate executable efort
  Could not locate executable efc
  customize PGroupFlangCompiler
  Could not locate executable flang
  don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    NOT AVAILABLE

  accelerate_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_info:
    libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_info:
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\mateu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c3kg6xo0\numpy_a0f8cbcefbea46f59d0a8ef8b828b848\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
      Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
      Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
      A better performance should be easily gained by switching
      Blas library.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
  blas_info:
    libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\mateu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c3kg6xo0\numpy_a0f8cbcefbea46f59d0a8ef8b828b848\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
      the BLAS environment variable.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
  blas_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\mateu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c3kg6xo0\numpy_a0f8cbcefbea46f59d0a8ef8b828b848\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
      the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
    NOT AVAILABLE

  non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_clapack_info:
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  flame_info:
    libraries flame not found in ['c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\libs
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\libs
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\libs
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\libs
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_info:
    libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mateu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\mateu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c3kg6xo0\numpy_a0f8cbcefbea46f59d0a8ef8b828b848\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\mateu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c3kg6xo0\numpy_a0f8cbcefbea46f59d0a8ef8b828b848\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
    FOUND:
      language = c
      define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

  Warning: attempted relative import with no known parent package
  c:\users\mateu\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running config_cc
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  build_src
  building py_modules sources
  creating build
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\distutils
  building library "npymath" sources
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Do you know if it is normal behaviour that the libraries cannot be installed? Is there any workaround?

Comment: can you post the full command output?

Comment: @N.Kern I posted the whole cmd output.

Comment: @BradSolomon unfortunately, it didn't help (I believe I tried it). but thanks!

Comment: This message seems to be critical: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`. My guess is that Visual C++ licensing somehow prevents numpy from bundling it with their application. Try installing the build tools they suggest and then re-doing the `pip install` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that some libraries that require compiling, such as numpy, included the pre-compiled binaries inside the installer (wheel) file. But they won't include binaries for non-stable releases (or niche architectures) - instead, the same file has the source code and some of the resources needed to build the binaries on the client (computer that is installing the library) side.

The error indicates that: the binaries are not included, and building them on your computer failed, probably likely to the lack of a build environment.
Under Linux it is more or less simple to install everything needed to build numpy (and other libraries). Setting up such an environment on Windows computer can be somewhat complicated.

You'd be better looking for an unofficial build wheel with the package pre-compiled for Python 3.10 - *if* numpy is already working with 3.10, which might not be the case: while for most end-user code no changes are needed changing from Python 3.9 to 3.10, projects like numpy depend heavily on internal details of the language.

One of the mirrors which keep pre-compiled binaries for various Python package seems to have a numpy for Python 3.10 on windows: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)  (please note that while looking alright, there is no mechanism to verify these packages are not adulterated from the source code, **as happens with all binary installs** (binary installs from official sources usually will have hashes or other verifying mechanisms + the certificate chain to the domain/brand names) , so, while I personally would use packages from lfd.uci.edu, this is not risk free)